# Toddish verify package error

Tags: laravel-4

I ran composer update today, and one of my package Toddish/Verify was d

```
Class Toddish\Verify\VerifyUserProvider contains 2 abstract methods and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods (Illuminate\Auth\UserProviderInterface::retrieveByToken, Illuminate\Auth\UserProviderInterface::updateRememberToken)
```

Have no idea how to fix it

**composer json**

```
        "require": {
        "laravel/framework": "4.1.*",
        "mews/captcha": "dev-master",
        "intervention/image": "dev-master",
        "moltin/laravel-cart": "dev-master",
        "davejamesmiller/laravel-breadcrumbs": "dev-master",
        "artdarek/oauth-4-laravel": "dev-master",
        "lucadegasperi/oauth2-server-laravel": "dev-master",
         "toddish/verify": "2.*",
        "doctrine/dbal": "~2.3",
        "pda/pheanstalk": "dev-master",
        "maatwebsite/excel": "dev-master"
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After [Laravel upgrading To 4.1.26](http://laravel.com/docs/upgrade#upgrade-4.1.26) you have to upgrade Todish pagackage

run in console **composer update**

```
$ composer update
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
- Removing toddish/verify (v2.3.1)
- Installing toddish/verify (v2.4.0)
Downloading: 100%
```